# String to Float is not working in java?

Tags: java, floating-point

The problem is simple:

```
float f1 = Float.parseFloat("41.975779") 
//Value for f1 is 41.97578  -> An error of 1ppm
```

And even worse!!

```
float f2 = Float.parseFloat("41.975645") 
//Value for f2 is 41.975643  -> An error of 2ppm
```

It doesn't matter if I use Float.parseFloat or Float.valueOf, they both give the same result.

Note: This problem occurs me when programing in android, I didn't try it in pure-java but I assume will be the same result.

Comment: Use the `BigDecimal` class for arbitrary precision signed floats. There are ways to convert a String to it, search other such posts for this.

Comment: As per @Kon's suggestion, please use BigDecimal. Not *all* fractions can be exactly represented in binary, hence the error. Please refer to the linked question for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string to float conversions are working *exactly* as advertised, although obviously not exactly as you expect :-)

IEEE754 single precision floating point values (as used in `float`) only have a precision of about seven decimal digits.

If you want more precision, use `double`, which provides about fifteen decimal digits, or switch to `BigDecimal` for arbitrary precision.

Just be aware that no encoding scheme can give you *infinite* precision, there will always be *some* values that can't be represented (unless you switch to symbolic representation of course).